# How to have Django serve an applet?

Tags: django, applet

I'm trying to show an applet at my web developed with Django. But it doesn't show and says nullpointerexception. This is because I don't know how to upload the .jar so that it can be reached by the applet calls.

I couln't find how to do it at the internet, how can I have Django serve an applet?

Thanks!

Comment: There's some information on [how to load an applet from a Django template here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259275/how-to-load-java-applet-from-django-template).

Answer (score 0):

An applet is simply a static file. So you should follow the standard rules for static files.

Comment: So do I have to create a method linked to a URL that deploys the applet and then in the HTML the "code" tag should reference that url?